# Как сделать выборку cql изменения данных клиента более года

Tags: oracle

Нужно сделать выборку по клиентам, которым вносили изменения более чем 1 год. Есть небольшие наброски, но выдает всех клиентов, которые изменены более года и в теч. года. 
Как задать условие, чтобы выдавал лишь клиентов, которые изменялись более 1 года.
Причем, есть тип `'ANKETA_SROK'` и `'ANKETA_DATEMODIFI'`

```
SELECT  eid,type/*ТИП ИЗМЕНЕНИЯ*/"ТИП ИЗМЕНЕНИЯ", VALUE /*ДАТА Обновления*/"ДАТА ОБНОВЛЕНИЯ", DATE_MODIFY/*ДАТА ИЗМЕНЕНИЯ*/"ДАТА ИЗМЕНЕНИЯ" 

--LAG(DATE_MODIFY) OVER(ORDER BY DATE_MODIFY) prev_DATE_MODIFY,

--LEAD(DATE_MODIFY) OVER(ORDER BY DATE_MODIFY) next_DATE_MODIFY

--LAG(VALUE,1,-999) OVER(ORDER BY VALUE) prev_VALUE, /*Предыдущее изменение*/

--LEAD(DATE_MODIFY/*,1,999*/) OVER(ORDER BY DATE_MODIFY) "СЛЕДУЮЩЕЕ ИЗМЕНЕНИЕ"

FROM eid.EID_HUMAN_OBJ_VARIABLE where 1=1

and type in ('ANKETA_SROK')
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Особенно что такое "клиенты, которые изменялись более 1 года". Приведите пример входных данных и что вы хотите получить на выходе

Comment: Получается анкета 115ФЗ должно быть изменения по клиенту не более года(т.е.) в теч. года по клиенту должно быть хоть одно изменение. Но есть клиенты, которые изменялись не в теч. года, а позже.

Comment: На выходе получается клиент, дата модификации(изменения), дата обновления( Дата обновления, зависит от даты модификации, при изменении(мод) меняется и дата обновления

Comment: не более года относительно чего ? не более года назад ? Или нужна разница между первым и последним изменением. Но при этом не позже чего должны быть эти самые изменения

Comment: Получается разница между датой обновления и последним изменением, чтобы дата изменения была больше года, что задан параметр даты обновления.
Допустим, дата обновления 01.01.2008, дата изменения 11.12.2009, этот клиент изменялся позже, чем указана дата обновления, он должен быть на выходе. если 01.01.2008 и изменение 01.01.2009(в этом интервале), то такой клиент не должен попасть на выходе

Comment: тогда чем `where date_modify - value > 365` не подходит ? вот то что вы словами пытаетесь объяснить можно выразить только так. Повторяю: нормально заданный вопрос по SQL обязательно включает в себя: **1.** create table создающую таблицу с нужной структурой **2.** insert into вставляющие в эту таблицу тестовые данные (в кайнем случае можно в виде таблички, но текстом, что бы можно было скопировать). **3.** пример таблицы которая должна получиться в результате выполнения запроса на приведенных данных. **4.** текстовое пояснение, почему именно такие данные получены

Comment: where date_modify - value > 365
Нужно попробовать